# Pan Gesture recognition and UIKit Dynamics Gravity

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, user-interface

I'm trying to make a game where objects fall from the sky (top of screen) and you have to pan an object left and right to avoid them. Pan gesture works fine but as soon as the objects (which are just other views with GCRects) start falling the pan gesture won't work. It just keeps reseting itself to its original position. To have the objects fall all I am doing is "spawning" them at the top of the screen and letting UIKit Dynamics and gravity do the rest to drop them down to the bottom. Any ideas how to have the gesture work concurrently with the falling objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you have accidentally (or intentionally) added the view you want to pan manually to the animator as a dynamic item. This means that the animator is responsible for positioning it, so on every frame of the animation it puts it back where it was, because it doesn't understand that you've moved it manually. So don't add it as a dynamic item, or else your pan gesture recognizer's action method should keep calling `updateItemUsingCurrentState:` on the animator - that is how you tell the animator that *you* have moved an item manually.